# in C or C++, how can I prevent previous #define in a header file from affecting another header file later included?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I think there may be no way of avoiding this but to change function/macro name, but I ask here just in case.

I have met a strange situation.

I'm trying (just started) to modify a program A (targeted for a dynamic library) so that the program uses a function in program B (this is not relevant for this question, but Program A is a simulator for an accelerator based on multi2sim written by my colleague, and program B is qemu, the famous CPU/machine emulator).

A file `driverA.cc` in program A looks like this:

```
#include "includeA.h"

#ifdef USED_IN_QEMU
#include "includeB.h"
#endif

// some code...
```

`includeA.h` has a macro like this:

```
#define set_pc(x) \
  do { p->check_pc_alignment(x); \
       npc = sext_xlen(x); \
     } while(0)
```

But `includeB.h` has this code:

```
static inline void cpu_set_pc(CPUState *cpu, vaddr addr)
{
    CPUClass *cc = CPU_GET_CLASS(cpu);
                 
    cc->set_pc(cpu, addr);
}
```

The compiler complains that `set_pc()` is supposed to take only one argument according to `includeA.h`, but `set_pc()` in `includeB.h` takes two arguments. I know it's just the same name but different functions or macros, but there arose conflicts between the include files. The compiler doesn't know they belong to different worlds.

How can I avoid this kind of compile error?

Comment: At the end of the header, `#undef set_pc`

Comment: @Eljay yeah that could be another solution, but the definition in includeA.h should be used later I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the order of the includes:

```
#ifdef USED_IN_QEMU
#include "includeB.h"
#endif

#include "includeA.h"
```

That way the macro in includeA.h doesn't affect anything in includeB.h.